# storing urls to a file so they can be reachable quickly

Tags: c++, list, file, search, hash

i have a file and a plenty of urls, these urls are written to a file all with the same structure plus a url CheckSum of type int. stackoverflow.com is written as:

```
    12534214214 http://stackoverflow.com
```

now everytime i want to put an url into the file i need to check if the url doesn't exist
then i can put it.
but it takes too much time to do this with 1 000 000 urls:

```
    //list of urls
    list<string> urls;
    size_t hashUrl(string argUrl); //this function will hash the url and return an int
    file.open("anchors");
    //search for the int 12534214214 if it isn't found then write 12534214214 http://stackoverflow.com
    file.close();
```

**question1** : -how can i search in a file using the checksum so the search will take a few ms?

**question2** : -is there another way of storing these urls so that they can be reachable quickly?

thanks, and sorry for bad english

Comment: Use a database. SQLite and BDB should be readily available.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your reply, i wanted to use database, but i need this to be sorted by checksums, so i can search for it easily, is that possible with a database?
@gha.st can you please explain how to sort a file by checksums ?ty in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (likely [1]) no way you search a million URLS in a plain text-file in "a few milliseconds". You need to either load the entire file into memory (and when you do, you may just as well do that into some reasonable data structure, for example a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`), or use some sort of indexing for the file - e.g have a smaller file with just the checksum and the place in the file that they are stored at.

The problem with a plain textfile is that there is no way to know where anything is. One line can be 10 bytes, another 10000 bytes. This means that you literally have to read every byte up to the point you are interested in.

Of course, the other option is to use a database library, SQLite etc (or proper a database server, such as MySQL) that allows the data to be stored/retrieved based on a "query". This hides all the index-generation and other such problems, and is already optimised both when it comes to search algorithms, as well as having clever caching and optimised code for reading/writing data to disk, etc.

[1] If all the URLS are short, it's perhaps possible that the file is small enough to cache well, and code can be written to be fast enough to linearly scan through the entire file in a few milliseconds. But a file with, say, an average of 50 bytes for each URL will be 50MB. If each byte takes 10 clock cycles to process, we're already at 130ms to process the file, even if it's directly available in memory.

Comment: hi mats, ty for your answer, i was talking about storing these URLS in a file that will be sorted by checksums , so i can do a binary search. is it possible ?

Comment: I just edited the file to explain that if it's a plain text-file, it's not possible to know where each entry is located. So I would suggest that the most plausible method is to simply load the entire file into memory (in a reasonably modern desktop machine, this should be no problem at all).

Comment: ty for your answer, just one last question, i read about binary file and maners that you can search something in it quickly, what do you think ?

Comment: If you have fixed size records, then text or binary file will work to search in a binary search. It's probably still not going to work well for your performance goals because of disk acesss speeds (and the file will be significantly larger if all records are big enough to hold very long URLs). If you don't need it to be a text-file, then use a database library/server.